# jQuery show elements with a range of values

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jQuery to show/hide elements based on the value of an attribute between two values.

I have markup that looks like this:

```
<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(0)" longdesc="0">1</a>
<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(1)" longdesc="1">2</a>
<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(2)" longdesc="2">3</a>
<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(3)" longdesc="3">4</a>
<a class="page_link active_page" href="javascript:go_to_page(4)" longdesc="4">5</a>
<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(5)" longdesc="5">6</a>
<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(6)" longdesc="6">7</a>
<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(7)" longdesc="7">8</a>
<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(8)" longdesc="8">9</a>
```

I have some jQuery that looks like this:

```
//Now, we need to paginate the pagination
var page_link_count = $('.page_link').length(); 

//Hide all the .page_links
$('.page_link').css('display','none'); 

//Show active_page
$('.active_page').css('display','block'); 

//Show up to four .page_link on either side of active_page
var active_page_value = $('.active_page').attr('longdesc'); 

$('.page_link').each(function(){

    var longdesc = $(this).attr('longdesc');

    // This next part might be what's getting me...
    if( longdesc <= active_page_value+4 && longdesc >= active_page_value-4){

        $(this).css('display','block');

    }

});
```

I'm trying to say, if the longdesc attribute value of any element with a page_link class is greater than the value of the sum of the active_page longdesc - 4 or less than the sum of  the active_page longdesc + 4

Comment: Don't mix Jquery with inline javascript. Just bad taste.

Comment: Much better: http://cssdeck.com/labs/tabs

Comment: What's a jQuery conditional look like?

Comment: I'm pretty confused by the question, could you try to rephrase what you are trying to accomplish? Specially the last paragraph, also what is the specific problem with you code? Does it give you an error? Why is it not working as expected?

Comment: Also, why are you using `.css();`? `.hide()` and `.show()` do the same exact thing.

Comment: So instead of `.css('display','block')` simply `.show()`?

Comment: `This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially.` [Verbatim Quote From JQuery .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: @yckart - Not what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **parse the number** before you add them . The values will be appended instead

```
if( (longdesc <= parseInt(active_page_value ,10) +4)
     &&( longdesc >= parseInt(active_page_value,10) -4))
```

---

**JS**

```
//Now, we need to paginate the pagination
var page_link_count = $('.page_link').length; 

//Hide all the .page_links
$('.page_link').css('display','none'); 

//Show active_page
$('.active_page').css('display','block'); 

//Show up to four .page_link on either side of active_page
var active_page_value = $('.active_page').attr('longdesc'); 

var min = parseInt(active_page_value,10) - 4;
var max = parseInt(active_page_value,10) + 4;

$('.page_link').each(function(){
    var longdesc = $(this).attr('longdesc');

    if( longdesc <= max && longdesc >= min){
        $(this).css('display','block');
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to change:

**Change**

```
var page_link_count = $('.page_link').length();
```

**To**

```
var page_link_count = $('.page_link').length;
```

**And**

```
var active_page_value = $('.active_page').attr('longdesc');
```

**To**

```
var active_page_value = +$('.active_page').attr('longdesc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Over complicating things...This is all you need.

```
//Hide all the .page_links
$('.page_link').hide(); 

//Show active_page
$('.active_page').show(); 

//Show all links before active
$('a.active_page').show();
$('a.active_page').prevAll().show();
```

*Note: the last two could be combined but I don't want to confuse you.